# Sublime Goto anything using dot notation

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3

When using Sublime 3, I'd like to search for a file using the "Dot notation", i.e. file names using `.` as the separator.

E.g. if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Goto Anything) and type `frontend/banks/index` it will find, for example, `frontend/banks/index.php`

But I want to type `frontend.banks.index`, which are used in Laravel's views.

How do I achieve this? Is this a sublime setting or a package?

Comment: To clarify: you want to find files *containing* some text? What happens when you search for strings with dots in them?

Comment: No I want to find the file in that path, but use . as folder separator

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Please clarify: In Sublime Text `Ctrl+F` opens the *Find* panel which is used to search for text in the active buffer/file/view. Are you asking how to search for a file name/path in the text of the active buffer? Or are you asking how to specify a file name/path in the *Where* field of the *Find In Files* panel which is opened with `Ctrl+Shift+F` (or `Super+Shift+F` on OSX)?

Comment: Sorry. Yes you are right. I meant Ctrl-P to find a file.

Comment: You don't have to type the whole thing. You could do `Ctrl+P  + frobaind` and still get the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer the question, and it makes an assumption for Sublime users: that you want/need this functionality to easily find view files in Laravel code, probably blade templates, based on the the de facto dot notation for view paths, eg.

```php
return view('frontend.banks.index');
```

PhpStorm users will know about (and rub your nose in) the functionality it offers when hovering over the view path. It will give you a pop-up with a list of files whose path matches the pattern.

The workaround I use for Sublime though is to use slash notation instead of dot notation, eg.

```php
return view('frontend/banks/index');
```

It's not well known that this works and I haven't seen it documented but it functions identically.

The downside to this is it breaks PhpStorm's above mentioned functionality. I recently got into a debate with a coworker over it. Since PhpStorm is more prevalent in the Laravel world, he won out. For my personal/solo projects, I use this syntax, and newcomers to the project using PhpStorm can suck it.

---

So, to wrap up my longwinded rant, here's my workflow to find a Laravel view in Sublime Text:

Prerequisite: write all view paths using slashes instead of dots in my codebase.

1. Highlight the view path
2. Copy to clipboard
3. cmd+p (or super+p, ctrl+p, based on your OS) to open the fuzzy file finder, whatever it's called
4. Paste
5. Open the desired file (if multiples match, otherwise just hit enter)

It's decent enough and doesn't require a mouse, like half of PhpStorm's best functionality.

---

PhpStorm functionality mentioned above:

(Edit: apparently this PhpStorm tooltip is just for auto-complete, which is nice, but to actually open the file, F12 should work with the cursor on the path string. Also, according to my coworker, F12 also works with slash notation, so that's very nice for PhpStorm users obviously. All said an done, I think slashes should be used for views in Laravel projects.)

[image]

Comment: This PhpStorm user would very much like that functionality, but it doesn't work like that for me.

Comment: I added a screenshot and a bit more of an explanation for the apparent PhpStorm functionality. Hopefully someone gets some sort of use out of this ridiculous answer. 

Comment: Nice, I was wanting to use this functionality literally an hour before your answer was posted, I made a mental note to look into it later. It does also work with slashes for me (I'm using the paid Laravel plugin, not the old free one, which may be the difference.)